# elastic search join query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I am having hard time doing join queries in elastic search. My use case is given a particular field and value for it in child document , retrieve the parent document.

I have established parent child relationship between two document following the documentation. When I tried to query, I dont get an error but I dont get any results as well. Following is the query

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "has_parent" : {
            "parent_type" : "<parent_type>",
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "name": "child_name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have loaded parent documents and child documents in the same index "my_index". I have established the mapping before loading documents. My mapping is as follows

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "parent_join": { 
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "<parent_type>": "<child_type>" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have added the routing number to be parent id while loading document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said you want to retrieve the parent document based on child's field but your query does the opposite. You want `has_child`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "has_child" : {
            "type" : "<child_type>",
            "query" : {
                "term" : {
                    "name" : "child_name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck.This is the response I get 
  {"took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}

Comment: @jojo I can't help you beyond this with the information you've provided. If you're still not getting results then either your query is wrong or your mappings are wrong (or both).

Comment: I dont do any mapping except to establish the parent-child relationship. I use logstash to load data to elastic-search. Before loading data via logstash, I do the below PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "parent_join": { 
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "<parent_type>": "<child_type>" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} Once this is done, I load data via logstash

Comment: @jojo just because you haven't supplied mappings doesn't mean they aren't there - I'd suggest it's time to dig a bit deeper into the ES documentation at this point and learn how to analyse your query.

Comment: thanks Ant. I found it. Now it seems to work. Issue was type is text for that field as follows. "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                              "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256 After changing it to keyword type, it worked fine. Yes, I need to dig deeper into ES docs to get better understanding